# Slick slider - How to link to slide on separate page

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Goal: have links on first page go to a specific slide on second page.
I can get it to go to the correct slide on the same page but not sure how to get it to go the slide on a separate page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a server-side language, by passing the slide in URL.
For example, in php, you can set slick slider option like this:

```
initialSlide: <?php echo $_GET['slide'] ?>
```